# Reading dbf file (visual dbase 7)

Tags: asp.net, oledb, dbf, dbase

I am developing an asp.net web application,I have some .dfb files to read, I can't read all dbf specially visual dbase 7 version , how can I solve this,even if I use another language and post it to my app in .net

I have used provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0 and it worked for certain tables

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Use a dedicated DBF library, e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DbfDataReader/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.